# Python (name "command" is not defined)

Tags: python, linux, macos, if-statement, function

I have the following code:

```
def main():
   command = raw_input('CMD#').lower()

if command == ("help"):
    help()
elif command == ("sniff"):
    sniff() 
else:
    print 'Error: Command Invalid'


main()
```

And I am getting the error message: **NameError: name 'command' is not defined.**

I am trying to loop a 'raw_input' defined as 'command' but i keep getting this error.  How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation of the main function is incorrect:

```
def main():
    command = raw_input('CMD#').lower()
    if command == ("help"):
        help()
    elif command == ("sniff"):
        sniff() 
    else:
        print 'Error: Command Invalid'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should indent the code as it's part of the `main` function:

```
def main():
    command = raw_input('CMD#').lower()

    if command == ("help"):
        help()
    elif command == ("sniff"):
        sniff() 
    else:
        print 'Error: Command Invalid'
```

In your code, the if/elif/else wasn't part of the `main` function so Python didn't know the value of `command` as that variable only gets a value inside `main`.